# Is it possible to make writing to files/reading from files safe for a questionnaire type website?

Tags: python, flask

My web app asks users 3 questions and simple writes that to a file, a1,a2,a3. I also have real time visualization of the average of the data (reads real time from file).

Must I use a database to ensure that no/minimal information is lost? Is it possible to produce a queue of read/writes>(Since files are small I am not too worried about the execution time of each call). Does python/flask already take care of this?

I am quite experienced in python itself, but not in this area(with flask).

Answer (score 0):

I see a few solutions:

- read /dev/urandom a few times, calculate sha-256 of the number and use it as a file name; collision is extremely improbable
- use Redis and command like LPUSH, using it from Python is very easy; then RPOP from right end of the linked list, there's your queue